# how to iterate JSON payload and construct the response in wso2

Tags: wso2-esb

How to iterate through results array and construct Response array by adding carValue and bikeValue into id ("C_05"-"B_08"/"C_07"/"B_06") of the Response array and keep the same desc as description.

**JSON Payload Request:**

```
{"results": [
      {
      "desc": "Blind",
      "carValue": "05",
      "bikeValue": "08"
   },
      {
      "desc": "Deaf",
      "carValue": "09",
      "bikeValue": "10"
   },
{
      "desc": "Oxygen",
      "carValue": "07"
   },
{
      "desc": "carbon",
      "bikeValue": "06"
   }]
}
```

**final Response should be:**

```
{
  "Response" : [
   {
    "id" : "C_05"-"B_08",
    "description" : "Blind"
   },
   {
    "id" : "C_09"-"B_10",
    "description" : "Deaf"
   },
   {
    "id": "C_07",
    "description": "Oxygen"
   },
   {
    "id": "B_06",
    "description": "carbon"
   }]
}
```

Comment: Which version of WSO2ESB are you using?

Comment: its wso2esb-5.0.0

Comment: You could use Datamapper mediator: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/WSO2+ESB+Data+Mapper+JSON+Schema+Specification

Comment: can you give an example, i dont think its possible by using Datamapper, we have condition to check before mapping and its array to array mapping based on the condition and also value which we are mapping to destination is not same as it is there in the source part. example related to my question will be more helpful..

Comment: I have not used json much and don't have the time to write a complete answer, but from what I gathered when looking at the Datamapper mediator, you can use concat on values - i.e. to concatenate the values of carValue and bikeValue, together with C_, B_ and then map the concatenated value to the id. This is xml to json, but they use concat there - https://nuwanpallewela.wordpress.com/2016/04/10/how-to-use-wso2-data-mapping-mediator-in-esb/

Comment: any updates ..!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the iterate, aggregate and script mediators, as I show you in this proxy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="proxyIterateJson"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>
                                        {"results": [&#xD;
                                                  {&#xD;
                                                  "desc": "Blind",&#xD;
                                                  "carValue": "05",&#xD;
                                                  "bikeValue": "08"&#xD;
                                           },&#xD;
                                                  {&#xD;
                                                  "desc": "Deaf",&#xD;
                                                  "carValue": "09",&#xD;
                                                  "bikeValue": "10"&#xD;
                                           },&#xD;
                                        {&#xD;
                                                  "desc": "Oxygen",&#xD;
                                                  "carValue": "07"&#xD;
                                           },&#xD;
                                        {&#xD;
                                                  "desc": "carbon",&#xD;
                                                  "bikeValue": "06"&#xD;
                                           }]&#xD;
                                        }
                        </format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <iterate xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  attachPath="//jsonObject"
                  expression="//jsonObject/results"
                  id="it1"
                  preservePayload="true">
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <property expression="$body//jsonObject/results/carValue"
                            name="carValue"
                            scope="default"
                            type="STRING"/>
                  <property expression="$body//jsonObject/results/bikeValue"
                            name="bikeValue"
                            scope="default"
                            type="STRING"/>
                  <property expression="$body//jsonObject/results/desc"
                            name="description"
                            scope="default"
                            type="STRING"/>
                  <script language="js">var carValue = mc.getProperty("carValue");
                                        var bikeValue = mc.getProperty("bikeValue");
                                        var desc = mc.getProperty("description");
                                        var concatValue;
                                        if(carValue == null || carValue == "") {
                                           concatValue = "B_" + bikeValue;
                                        } else if(bikeValue == null || bikeValue == "" ){
                                           concatValue = "C_" + carValue;
                                        }else {
                                           concatValue = "C_"+ carValue + "-" + "B_" + bikeValue;
                                        }
                                        print("Value concatenado: "+ concatValue );
                                        mc.setProperty("concatValue", concatValue);
                                        mc.setPayloadJSON({"result":{"id" : concatValue,"description" : desc}});</script>
                  <log>
                     <property expression="json-eval($.result.id)" name="JSON-Payload"/>
                  </log>
                  <loopback/>
               </sequence>
            </target>
         </iterate>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <property name="res" scope="default">
            <ns:Response xmlns:ns="www.response.org"/>
         </property>
         <aggregate id="it1">
            <completeCondition>
               <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
            </completeCondition>
            <onComplete enclosingElementProperty="res" expression="$body//result">
               <log level="custom" separator=",">
                  <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="OUPUTSECUENSE"/>
               </log>
               <send/>
            </onComplete>
         </aggregate>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence/>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

This is the response

```
{"Response":
    {"result":[
        {"id":"C_09-B_10","description":"Deaf"},
        {"id":"C_05-B_08","description":"Blind"},
        {"id":"C_07","description":"Oxygen"},
        {"id":"B_06","description":"carbon"}
]}}
```

You can also use custom or payloadFactory mediator to generate the Json response

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Writing+a+WSO2+ESB+Mediator

Comment: thanks for your answer, will try out your solution in my free time. I tried using simple script mediator and calling it from api and its working for.