# How to store all the json objects from an iterator into one Array in wso2 ESB

Tags: wso2-esb

I have an json output which looks like,

```
"details": [
        {
            "id": "",
            "name": "",

            "status": "",

        },
       {
            "id": "",
            "name": "",

            "status": "",

        },
       {
            "id": "",
            "name": "",

            "status": "",

        },
       {
            "id": "",
            "name": "",

            "status": "",

        }
```

From this output I can iterate values like **//jsonObject/details** and fetching individual item like
`json-eval('$.details.id')`, but I want to store all Id's and Name's into a Array in wso2 ESB, from the output I get, Can anyone help me.

Comment: I want to store all id's and name's like [id:name, id2:name2, id3:name3].

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that helps, I think the following pseydo code might do it but I haven't tried it.

```
    //create an empty var

<property name="newArray" value=""/>

//iterate over the json
<iterate xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" continueParent="true" expression="//jsonObjects/object" id="MyIterator">
....
    <property name="newArray" expression="fn:concat(get-property('newArray'),//jsonObjects/object/value)" scope="operation"/>
    ....
</iterate>

<log>
    <property name="afterIterate" expression="get-property('operation','newArray')"/>
</log>
```

Comment: Thank You, I guess, it works, I have not tried this but, I found one answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290694/how-to-iterate-json-payload-and-construct-the-response-in-wso2